# Could ConnectionPooling or lack thereof, be the explanation for this odd Sql Compact performance

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm considering using Sql Server Compact 4.0 for the data store for a windows service app (not web).

I was concerned about the performance of my service with multiple callers, so I drafted a small test, and the results were exactly opposite to my expectations.  (See code below)

The test simply adds 500 rows to a table in a simple database that is created using code first with Entity Framework 5.0.

The way it adds the rows is particular.  It calls the AddRow method 500 times, and leaves it to the AddRow method to create a instance of the DbContext, and add the row then dispose of the context. The reason I do it like this is that the loop that calls AddRow 500 times is to simulate 500 calls from a client (albeit in rapid succession which you may say is not realistic)

To simulate multiple clients, I start a number of tasks to do the work of the LoadData method.

Now for the observations:
With one thread calling LoadData, and in the end calling AddRow 500 times, the time on my workstation to add 500 rows is ~50 seconds (a meager 10 rows per second!)

With 5 threads calling LoadData, I expected each thread to execute at best in ~50 seconds, but instead 4 for of the 5 threads completed in 3 seconds, and the last thread in 10 seconds.

I assume the last thread ran longer, because after 3 seconds the 4 other threads had finished, and so the last thread was running solo, and it would seem that running solo in this test results in disastrous performance.

I should note that if I change from Sql Compact to Local DB then the performance is exactly as expected: each thread runs in approximately the same time, ~3 seconds.

Here's the complete code and app.config, which you should be able to cut and paste into a new Visual Studio 2012 Console project.

At the moment, my best guess, is that in the single thread test, there is no connection pool happening, but that somehow there is in the other tests?  This doesn't make any sense to me, and my question is what should be done, to make the test run with a single caller thread just as fast as with multiple caller threads?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SqlCompactPerf
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MaxThreads = 5;
        private const int RowsToInsert = 500;
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
                context.Database.Delete();


            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (var threadCount = 1; threadCount <= MaxThreads; threadCount++)
                tasks.Add(Task<TimeSpan>.Factory.StartNew(LoadData)
                                        .ContinueWith(x => 
                                           Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", x.Result)));

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            using (var context = new MyContext())
                Console.WriteLine("Expecting {0}, Found {1}",
                    RowsToInsert * MaxThreads,
                    context.Rows.Count());

        }

        static TimeSpan LoadData()
        {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            for (var i = 1; i <= RowsToInsert; i++)
            {
                AddRow(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
            watch.Stop();

            return watch.Elapsed;
        }

        static void AddRow(string data)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.Rows.Add(new Row { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Data = data });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Row
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the App.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>-->
</configuration>
```

Comment: woth running inteelitrace on this lot. And/or SQL profiler.  You may much of the time is loading ef model. which is ordinary.  But when loaded things are "ok".  you may find this useful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853

Comment: I don't think I can run SQL Profiler on a Sql CE database since there isn't server to connect to.

Comment: ok, but intellitrace should help

Comment: Why new MyContext() in AddRow?   This is a lot of overhead.  Why not just new it once and hold it?

Comment: @Blam ordinarily it's not a lot of overhead -- and in fact in using LocalDB that approach of open as late as possible and close as early as possible works great.  Secondly, this sample is to simulate a normally stateless server that is receiving messages from clients (as represented by the one or more concurrent threads) and each client sending a single add row request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to always keep at least one database connection open for the lifetime of the app, as Opening the first connection is resource intensive. But do not share the same SqlCeConnection object across threads. This link explains an approach you can adapt: http://matthewmanela.com/blog/sql-ce-3-5-with-linq-to-sql/ - in addition, adding many rows using EF5 or earlier is slow due to a bug, that I have fixed in EF6 - see my blog post here for more info: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/06/inserting-many-rows-with-entity.html